# Degrees of freedom of a three dimensional polyatomic molecules

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, molecules, degrees-of-freedom

> An ideal gas consists of three dimensional polyatomic molecules. The temperature is such that only one vibrational mode is excited. If $R$ denotes the gas constant, then the specific heat at constant volume of one mole of the gas at this temperature is:

The method I used is that
$$C_v=\frac{f}{2}R$$
Where Cv = specific heat at constant volume
f= degree of freedom

Given that it is a 3-D polyatomic molecules, it would have the following degrees of freedoms

a) 3 translational degree freedom

b) 3 Rotational degree of freedom

c) 1 vibrational degree of freedom ( given in question)

Total degree of freedoms are 7, hence
$$Cv=\frac{7}{2}R$$

The twist, however, is that the answer is $$Cv=4R$$

*Can someone explain where the 8th degree of freedom came from? or Is it that the answer given is wrong?*

Comment: this question has been answered  about two days back...appears to be duplicate..the wording is  different.

Comment: Any link of the question?

Comment: searching for it....

Comment: Hint: In vibrational mode - a vibration involves both kinetic and potential energy terms which are squares of velocity and coordinate thereby on the average it may contribute two degrees of freedom..

Comment: If that is the case then how come diatomic molecules have 6 degrees of freedom ( 3 translational, 2 rotational and 1 vibrational) and not 7 degrees of freedom ( 3 translation, 2 rotational and 2 due to vibrations)

Comment: Shikhar Asthana -Vibrations in polyatomic molecules are described by normal coordinates . molecule can have a total of 3N degrees of freedom, and can be grouped into three categories. Translational ,Rotational and Vibrational: These vibes are any other types of movement not assigned to rotational or translational movement and thus there are 3N – 6 degrees of vibrational freedom for a nonlinear molecule and 3N – 5 for a linear molecule. see< chem.libretexts.org/Textbook_Maps/… – drvrm 32 mins ago

Answer (score 1):

Your formula for Cv is wrong. The formula u used is for that condition when Vibrational mode is absent. 
Actual in general  formula is
Cv= ( ft/2 + fr/2 + fv) R
Now using these u will get the value as 4R.

Answer (score 0):

The degrees of freedom for a 3D polyatomic gas molecule are $6$ at normal temperature. But as there is only one vibrational mode so the degrees of freedom become $6+2=8$. Hence $C_v=fR/2$ so $C_v=4R$. Here we add 2 because in a polyatomic gas molecule no.of vibrational mode is $3N-6$ (for non linear). So $3 \cdot 3-6=3$. But only one vibrational mode is active so degrees of freedom become $8$.

Comment: Please use mathjax for formatting

Answer (score -1):

Cv=(3+f)R. As, f=1,  Cv=4R
Cp=(4+f)R

Answer (score -1):

one vibrational mode contributes 2 degrees of freedom hence 3+3+2 = 8
then (8/2)R = 4R